# Skoda Fabia windows don't work, at night one window opened

Tags: power-windows, skoda, fabia

My dad has Skoda Fabia and there's two front windows that should open/close with buttons, but it doesn't work for 5 months (other two windows at back open manually).

Yesterday at night(after rain) driver(left) window was opened somehow.
Car was locked. It never happened before.

I found that there's a feature with keys to open and close windows by holding lock/unlock button. It didn't work.

We need to close that window somehow or if it's possible fix both windows.

Edit:
I should have mentioned that it's 2007 fabia, on left there's 2 buttons for left and right windows, on right there's one button for right window. All windows buttons don't work.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest the issue lies with the button itself. Obviously if it was down, it has power and the motor works. If you pull up the switch unit and figure out which is power from the battery and which goes out to the window motor, you should be able to apply power to motor and bring it back to the upright position.

If for some reason there's no power coming from the battery side (make sure the key is on), then you can apply a 12vdc source to the window motor directly to get it to operate.

It's also not usual for both switches to go bad at the same time (or nearly the same time). They are probably a pair, anyway, and come together, so replacing them shouldn't be too big of a deal.

Comment: I should have mentioned that it's 2007 fabia, on left there's 2 buttons for left and right windows, on right there's one button for right window. All windows buttons don't work.

Comment: @AlgirdasButkus - A lot of cars pass the power from the main (driver's side) to the passenger side, or use the driver's side as a relay to get the power to the windows. It's stupid, but it's that way. Even so, I addressed just getting power to the window and getting it rolled up in my answer, which was really the gist of your question.